# Inflate a layout in another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am working on Navigation Drawer Layout. Another layout must load in place of the 
drawer_layout onClick of the navigation items.

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

  //code to inflate another layout inplace of current layout
  //setContentView(R.layout.another_layout1);


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

  //code to inflate another layout inplace of current layout
  //setContentView(R.layout.another_layout2);

    }
```

How to load another layout in the mainlayout.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio navigation drawer with fragment or activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079028/android-studio-navigation-drawer-with-fragment-or-activities)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334048/android-layout-replacing-a-view-with-another-view-on-run-time

Comment: use **`Fragments`**

Comment: if you want to load different layout then use baseactivty  and load each layout their in its oncreate method.!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create fragment
**(Right click on your project -> New -> Fragment)**.then load inside Activity below this..

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

     CameraFragment camera = new CameraFragment();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();              
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, camera, "HELLO");
     fragmentTransaction.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

     GalleryFragment gallery = new GalleryFragment();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();              
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, gallery, "HELLO");
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```